# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out in corda node

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, corda

While initiating flow from spring web server by passing required values from PartyA to PartyB in corda, I am getting following exception in my initiating node PartyA, kindly do the needfull.

```
entered verifysend method
E 12:01:47+0530 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@6cb2b947)] core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
=========collecting ended=========
```

Even through my flow is running successfully by giving response as `Transaction id:.... commited to ledger` in web server, but my flow is taking `around 5 minutes to create a unconsumed state.`

Comment: can anyone help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are run into low-memory issue, so one of your nodes was crashed. Hence lead to the handshake error.

The current minimal requirement for starting a node is 1GB of JVM Heap and 2GB minimal host RAM.